# Are there any disadvantages to using 'count' php-side for counting the number of rows

Tags: php, mysql

Just wondering if I'd face any problems counting the number of rows returned in a query as shown below.

```
$stm = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `mytable`");
$stm->execute();

$data = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "rows: ".count($data);
```

As opposed to using

```
$stm = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mytable`");`
```

Performance-wise, which is better and will it cause any problems for a relatively small-sized database (no more than 1k rows).

Comment: SQL will probably be faster at just getting a count than returning every column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it with SQL `select count(*) ...` returns just one row, whereas `select * ...` returns many rows. So there's a significant communication overhead. Additionally, if you don't have a `where` clause, the server might just lookup the number of rows. In contrast PHP must count the rows entirely.

With a small database, you probably don't notice the difference, but it doesn't hurt to be performance conscious from the beginning.

Comment: But say if I were to utilise all rows returned by the query, then would it be acceptable to count the rows php-side?

Comment: @sooper When you need the rows anyway, there should be no overhead. Although I don't know, how `count($data)` is implemented, it should be just a lookup as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using `COUNT(*)` is much better. MySQL doesn't need to access all the data and the data also isn't send tot the client.

Read about [`COUNT(*)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) in the MySQL manual.

Comment: +1 for the man page link.  And if you've got a big table with lots of rows and columns, SELECT * is going to transfer all of that unnecessary data.  Even if it's only a thousand rows of unnecessary data, you shouldn't proliferate it if you do not need it.